# volley error when importing module

Tags: android, json

I've been trying to add the volley library to my android project by downloading this repository https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley and then importing the module to my project by following this guide:

> First get latest volley with git (git clone >https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley).
>   In your current project (android studio) click [File] --> [New] -->[Import >Module].
>   Now select the directory where you downloaded Volley to.
>   Now Android studio might guide you to do the rest but continue guide to verify >that everything works correct
>   Open settings.gradle (find in root) and add (or verify this is included):
>
> include ':app', ':volley'
>   Now go to your build.gradle in your project and add the dependency:
>
> compile project(":volley").

When gradle tries to sync the project after I've imported the module i get the following error message : Error:Could not download layoutlib-api.jar (com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:24.3.1): No cached version available for offline mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to use `Volley` and not contribute to the volley library. if that is the case there are better ways to get volley in your project. let `Gradle` handle it. `Gradle` is Build Management tool just like Maven but better, As it gives you more freedom and flexibility.

[How to add libraries to gradle](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-without-res) in android studio. this link shows a how to add libraries to your android project.

As Android Studio uses `Gradle` things are pretty neat as it uses the middle ground of `ANT` and `Maven` for Build and Management tool.

for volley you can add 
`compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'`
to the app module of your project. this library can be looked up on [Github](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley)

or you can do that using android studio's GUI, click on **File -> Project Structure**

[image]

[example](https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/build.gradle)